# Authority gem gives 'undefined method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, authority-gem

I'm getting `undefined method 'authorize_actions_for'` in the controller when using [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) with the [Authority gem](https://github.com/nathanl/authority). Any ideas what I need to include? Here's my code:

**Gemfile:**

```
...
gem 'authority', '~> 2.9.0'
gem 'rails-api', '~> 0.1.0'
...
```

**app/authorizers/session_authorizer.rb:**

```
class SessionAuthorizer < ApplicationAuthorizer
  def deletable_by?(user)
    user.sessions.include?(resource)
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/v1/sessions_controller.rb:**

```
class V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  authorize_actions_for Session
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Include `Authority::Controller`

[As we discussed on Github](https://github.com/nathanl/authority/issues/64), `authorize_actions_for` is defined in `Authority::Controller`.

In a normal Rails app, that module gets included into `ActionController::Base` by Authority's `railtie.rb`. Apparently the railtie isn't being required when using rails-api (maybe the `Rails` constant isn't defined?).

You can include the appropriate module yourself, though:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Authority::Controller
end
```